# Starting multiple firefox profiles with batch file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, command-line

It is possible to start different firefox profile with `firefox -P <profile-name> -no-remote`

However, when I want to start multiple profiles with batch file in linux simultaneously, only the first profile starts and the subsequent profiles do not start until the previous is quit.

At the moment I am unsuccessful with this batch script:

```
#! /bin/bash

firefox -P "profile 1" -no-remote
firefox -P "profile 2" -no-remote
firefox -P "profile 3" -no-remote
```

Basically, `profile 1` starts fine but `profile 2` does not start until I quit firefox first; the next command does not get executed until the previous is quit.

In Windows, I have successfully managed to start multiple firefox simultaneously using this bat file:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "profile 1" 
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "profile 2" 
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "profile 3"
```

The quotes after `start` help accomplish this, without quotes after `start`, profiles don't all start at the same time, but in linux I have no idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: you need to run them in the background by adding an `&` to the end of the commands

Comment: Wow, what a noob I am! One symbol can kill or keep you alive. Thanks so much! All profiles are starting simultaneously

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn: please post as an answer so that OP can accept it and thus mark this as resolved.

Comment: moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run them in the background by adding an

```
  &
```

to the end of the commands

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me when i searched threw the internet

```
@echo off

start firefox.exe -P Profile1 -no-remote
start firefox.exe -P Profile2 -no-remote
start firefox.exe -P Profile3 -no-remote
```